# Prove that for any sets A and B there is a unique C such that $A \triangle C=B$; C is not unique!

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation, fake-proofs

From *How to Prove It*

> Prove that for any sets A and B there is a unique set C such that $A \triangle C=B$

The immediate answer is $C=A\triangle B$, which then works, since $A \triangle (A \triangle B) = (A \triangle A) \triangle B$ by associativity of symmetric difference.

But I don’t think this answer is unique.

Notice that $A\triangle B=\{x|x\in (A-B) \vee x\in (B-A) \} = (A-B)\cup(B-A)$

Let $C=A\cup B$. Then we have $A \triangle (A \cup B) = (A-(A\cup B)) \cup (A\cup B-A)$

$(A-(A\cup B)) = \emptyset$ , since there is no x such that $x\in A$ but $x \notin (A\cup B)$.

$(A\cup B - (A)) =B$, since if $x\in A\cup B$ but $x\notin A$, it must be that $x\in B$

so  $A \triangle (A \cup B) = (A-(A\cup B)) \cup (A\cup B-A)$ = B.

so C is not unique at all. But the textbook problem assumes that it is, and asks us to prove it. Is my proof that C isn’t unique incorrect? What am I missing?

Comment: The symmetric difference of two sets is the set of elements in one or the other but not both, Your second choice for $C$ omits the part of $B$ that's not in $A$. I haven't looked through your argument to find the particular error. Draw Venn diagrams.

Comment: No, in general $(A\cup B) -A \neq B$ you can clearly see that when considering e.g. the case $B=A$.  Rather it should be $(A\cup B) -A = B-A$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you give is incorrect, $C = A\cup B$ does not satisfy $A\triangle C = B$. There is an equivalent definition of $\triangle$, $A\triangle B = A\cup B - A\cap B$. Then the second choice of $C = A\cup B$ you suggested gives $$A\triangle (A\cup B) = (A\cup A \cup B) -A\cap (A\cup B) = A \cup B - A\cup (A\cap B) = B- (A\cap B),$$ which is $B-A$. And $B-A$ does not contain all of $B$ when $A\cap B$ is non-trivial.

Your argument turns awry when you claim $A\cup B - A = B$. The left hand side is missing elements of $B\cap A$, which is nonempty in general, while the right hand side still has them.

The choice you first provide for $C$ is forced, if we notice that $A\triangle C = B$ means that $A \triangle (A\triangle C) = A\triangle B$. The left hand side becomes $(A\triangle A) \triangle C= \emptyset \triangle C = C$, using the facts that $S\triangle S = \emptyset$ and $\emptyset \triangle S = S$ for all $S$. Then $C = A\triangle B$.